# How to set image transparency color?

Tags: html, css, transparency, rgba

Having some problems with adding a different color to my transparency. Previously it was a black fill on top of the image, so when I hover my image to it, the shade would light open. However, when I tried adding a red rgba color to it, the transparency remains the same color.

```
    img {
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    img:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `color`property to `background-color`.

***CSS***

```
img {
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

img:hover {
opacity:1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2) !important;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dPhWy/3/)

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately the shade is still black.

Comment: Probably you're using an image with black shade... :) Or probably you're using `box-shadow` in your _CSS_. Please provide your image.

Comment: Unless it's not appearing on firefox.

Comment: Anyway, `color` parameter **always** sets the font color.

Comment: @FranciscoCarvalho the code is from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)

Comment: I am using firefox. Already tested in *MAC OS Safari* and *Chrome* and it worked... @vishalkin what does you mean with _the code is from w3schools_?

Comment: @FranciscoCarvalho / Vishalkin is referring that the transparency I got was from w3schools. And he is correct, and maybe that could be the case to the problem?

Comment: @FranciscoCarvalho i mean the code posted by the questioner (Brian Lam) is from W3S.. i just gave a reference link.

Comment: @brianlam, I am too blind for know. LOL What is the real issue here? :)

Comment: @ Franscisco: it's still about the transparency. The shade hasn't turned red as it should be with the rgba code added.

Comment: Because your `:hover` selector has `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)`, you need to change `0.2`to `1`. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dPhWy/4/)

Comment: Still remain the same, I think I will post a screenshot of what I'm getting, maybe that would be clearer.

Comment: Or a link, but its just incorrect in the terms of SO. Come on, just trying to help.